# How to distribute Apache Flume 1.4

Tags: apache, flume

I looked at Apache Flume 1.4 documentation and its not clear about how to distribute the work accross nodes. I have to fetch data from multiple sources and multiple query terms for each source and need to poll them regularly. Older versions of Flume for flume-master and flume-node(s). Cloudera release notes says these concepts are replaced by Agents. But how to distribute the agents?

Should I manually create multiple configurations on each node and start agents on each of the node? or can be done through any centralized mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Flume agents in Cloudera Manager - see [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Free/4.5.4/Cloudera-Manager-Free-Edition-User-Guide/cmfeug_topic_5_1.html) (section Adding Flume). If you don't use Cloudera, it is possible to solve this problem with general purpose configuration management tools such as [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source/) - it seems to be more flexible, although requires more effort.